# How to preprocess address, latitude and longitude features in tabular data for Pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, feature-extraction, tabular

I have cleared my data into the next 6 columns that you see ahead that it is my **input** data. I split the dataset to have the label in another variable Y.

My main problem: I don't know how to preprocess the data to have a good input to any model.

My dataset X looks like this:

| desc | tipo | address | region | latitude | longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Galpón | Industria | Subdivisión de la Finca Denominada Violeta S/N | Región de Arica y Parinacota-Arica | -19.423411 | -11.371551 |

- desc - string
- tipo - string
- address - string
- region - string
- latitude - string
- longitude - string

My dataset Y looks like

| CIO |
| --- |
| 169379 |

### What I tried

I have followed this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-for-tabular-data-using-pytorch-1807f2858320) that allows me to comprehend a little bit about tabular data, but the data is completely different and I don't know if it fits me as well. So, my code transformed all the data to a LabelEncoder, but it is obvious that doesn't apply to latitude and longitude.

```
for col in df.columns:
    if df.dtypes[col] == "object":
        df[col] = df[col].fillna("NA")
    else:
        df[col] = df[col].fillna(0)
    df[col] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df[col])

for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].astype('category')
```

Also, the author used some Categorical Embedding that I don't know if works properly with my kind of data too.